# IntelliJ heap size error after increasing memory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I get the following error after increasing the heap size to 2048 in IntelliJ 2016.1.1

(I'm running with Java in 32 bit, as an included library is not available in 64bit.)

I have so far no experiences with compiler errors due to JVM so any help is appreciated.

Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java32\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-4014826147147167521 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2016.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\Yann.IntelliJIdea2016.1\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\Yann.IntelliJIdea2016.1\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/log/build-log -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/compile-server/*temp* -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Yann\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-5807041744380420603-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java32/jdk1.8.0_101/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jsr166e.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/netty-all-4.1.0.Beta8.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/picocontainer.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/openapi.jar;;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-3.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-plugins-3.0.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/compiler-settings.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/scala-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/jline.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-play-2-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 55014 f4d655a1-23db-4ba8-84ab-ebc487bef09d C:/Users/Yann/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/compile-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2048M is too much memory for a 32 bit JVM. Try to lower the heap size setting. Another option would be to run IntelliJ IDEA on a 64 bit JVM, which it should be able to do without any problems.

To further investigate the problem, you can also inspect the build.log. Use the `Help | Show Log in Explorer` menu item and then look in the `build-log` folder to find it. It should contain more information about why the build process was terminated.

Comment: thanks, I finally managed to arrange my code to run with 1024MB memory. Sadly the xuggle lib doesn't work flawlessly with 64bit JVM and mp4 files, to I first tried this solution. Thank you for the information, I will keep it in mind if I code something for 32 Bit JVM

Comment: It should cause no problems for IntelliJ IDEA to run on a 64 bit JVM, while your project uses a 32 bit JVM. You just need to have both JVMs installed on your system (and IntelliJ IDEA includes its own JVM, so you basically only have to install a JDK for your project).